# Where are the files for Node-Red related to Language?

Tags: github, translation, node-red

I've been using and enjoying the Node-Red for many years and i would like to contribute. I'm not good at coding, but I want to add translation to Brazillian Portuguese (pt-BR). I have forked the gitHub repo but i couldn't find where are the code for translation. Where can i find them?

I've tried to look around, find some text like "language", "en-US" etc. but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really the right place to ask this (the Node-RED forum or Slack would be the correct place) but the core editor translations can be found in

```
node-red/packages/@node-red/editor-client/locales
```

And the translations for the core nodes are

```
node-red/pacakges/@node-red/nodes/locales
```

Please make sure you read the contributing guide (https://github.com/node-red/node-red/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) before submitting any work and since the core Node-RED team do not speak Portuguese, please try and reach out to the community to help find native speakers that can help to check your work.

Comment: Thanks, man. I'll read the contributing guide before start my work. About the native speaker, I'm one. I'm from Brazil. Thanks for the tips. Helped a lot.

Comment: I mean we will need somebody other than yourself to review your changes (so you are no marking your own homework so to speak), as we can't check them ourselves